# Shuffle method results in repeating pattern?

Tags: java, random

I have an array of JButtons with String filenames set on them as text (t's a little hard to explain but the filenames specify the images, so when I want to set an icon for a specific button, I have a method to pull the filename text from the button and use it to setIcon). The String filenames are stored in a String array, and I'm trying to shuffle the Strings around but the problem is when I run my program the filenames aren't shuffled properly. They do have random positions, but I have 24 matching pairs of filenames and the matching ones are always 3 buttons apart from each other every time I run it, which is clearly not random. Does anyone know why this is happening? I doubt it's a problem with my setFace method because I'm using the shuffled array.. help would be appreciated!

```
public void shuffle()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) 
   {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 24);
        temp[i] = country[rand]; //temp is a temporary array
        country[rand] = country[i];//country is the filename array
        country[i] = temp[i];
   }

  card.setBack(cards); 
  card.setFace(country, cards); //cards is the 48 button array
 }

public void setFace(String[] file, JButton[] buttons) //filename method
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
  {
     buttons[i].setText(file[i]);
  }
  int ct = 0;
  for(int x = 24; x < 48; x++)
  {
     buttons[x].setText(file[ct]);
     ct++;
  }
}

public void setBack(JButton[] array) //sets back icon of card
{
  icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("back.png"));
  img = (icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(75, 95, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
  thomas = new ImageIcon(img);

  for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
  {
     array[x].setIcon(thomas);
  }
}
```

The non-random arrangement that I'm talking about is like this:

```
Card A     Card R
Card D     Card H
Card F     Card Z
Card A     Card R
Card D     Card H
Card F     Card Z
```

Comment: Use java.util.Collections.shuffle

Comment: @Toilal is it a problem with my shuffle method? also, this is for a project so I'd prefer to reinvent the wheel this time around.

Comment: Side note: in your `setFace(...)` you could add `button[i+24].setText(file[i])` to make it easier to read and get rid of the second loop. Besides that there are some issues like not checking the length of the array (you need to be very careful then), using multiple identical versions of the same image (memory usage), the use of a non-local temporaray array (`temp`, which actually doesn't need to be an array at all) etc. - What I don't get is your problem: what are the matches that should be different and how do you shuffle those?

Comment: In your example, what are the "matching pairs of filenames"? Is it A-A or A-R?

Comment: @Thomas All of the filenames should be randomly arranged in the array of buttons, and I have a String array (country) to store the filenames. Then I have a shuffle method to randomize the country array, and a method to set the filenames back onto the buttons as text. I don't understand what you mean by "how do you shuffle those", though, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Thomas A-A, I just arranged the cards in an imitation of an array. The same letters correspond to each other. Do you see what I mean by the buttons always being three away from each other? the second Card A is three down from the first, and that's how it is for all of the different filenames.

Comment: What I mean is this: assume you have an array of 26 characters like A,B,C,D etc. If you shuffle those you still should have an array of 26 individual characters. Where do the matches come from? You're basically assigning 24 strings to 48 buttons in a way that buttons 0 and 24 get the same text as well as 1 and 25, 2 and 26 etc.

Comment: Your shuffle method also has a drawback: you could end up swapping an element with itself if `rand = i` or swap elements back, i.e. you could swap 1 with 2 and in the next step 2 with 1. You might do it like `Collections.swap` instead: iterate backwards and take a random index up to (but not including) the current index, i.e. `rand = random() * i` (and you might use `Random` instead of `Math.random()`).

Comment: @Thomas My aim was to shuffle the filenames and randomly assign them to different buttons, and the same filenames should be matches, because there would be a duplicate of each filename. Am I assigning buttons 0 and 24 the same filename in setFace, though?

Comment: Effectively yes, have a look at the second loop and the first part of my first comment. In the second loop you're iterating from 24 to 47 and increment `ct` at the end of each iteration effectively assigning it the values 0 to 23 in order. Then you're calling `buttons[x].setText(file[ct]);` which results in `buttons[24].setText(file[0]);`,  `buttons[25].setText(file[1]);` etc.

Comment: @Thomas I understand what you're saying, but when I do

 `for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        buttons[i+24].setText(file[i]);
     }`
 it results in the first 24 buttons being blank with no text.

Comment: That's why I wrote "add" that (i.e. remove the second loop and add that one line to the body of the first loop, without removing what's already in that body). ;) - Do you want the second batch of buttons (indices 24-47) to have a different order? Is that the match shuffling you're talking about?

Comment: @Thomas I'm really sorry to keep bothering you but that would result in the same assignment problem. Would it work if I shuffled the country array in between the two assignment statements? edit: yes, they are all supposed to be randomly placed

Comment: I think I begin to understand what your problem is. Let me check: assume we have the array A,B,C,D - you now have 8 buttons, i.e. 2 groups of 4 which should display the elements in a random order but each group containing each element only once, right? So you could end up with A,C,D,B (group 1) - B,D,A,C (group2) but _not_ A,A,D,C - B,C,D,B - right?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, and theoretically they wouldn't even be in groups in the array, if they were placed randomly button A could be placed right next to the first button A. I just need all of the 48 filenames to be in a random position.

Comment: So A,A,D,C,B,C,D,B would be ok?

Comment: @Thomas if it helps to get some context, this is for a picture memory match game, so the pairs should be scattered, definitely not in the pattern shown in the original question.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but only if it were random and not as a result of a pattern

Comment: Ah, the memory game context makes it clearer. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a set of elements in a random order and use each element twice you have several ways to do it:

1.) Create an array/list of the elements and add each element twice then shuffle and display it (set the button texts in your case).

2.) Create a list of elements and add each element twice. Then iterate over the buttons and extract a random element from the list (remove it). You could do it like this:

```
List<String> elements = ...;//create the list, like A,A,B,B,C,C etc.
Random r = new Random();
for( JButton b : buttons ) {
  //get a random element
  int index = r.nextInt( elements.size() ); //index is between 0 and list size exclusive
  String element = elements.remove( index ); //remove the element which returns it as well
  b.setText( element );
}
```

3.) Do it like no. 2 but iterate over the elements and select 2 random buttons:

```
List<JButton> buttons = ...; //temporary list of buttons
Random r = new Random();
for( String element : elements ) {
  //remove a random button from the list and assign it the text
  buttons.remove( r.nextInt( buttons.size() ) ).setText(element);
  buttons.remove( r.nextInt( buttons.size() ) ).setText(element);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question: what is the b: buttons line? I've never seen something like that.

Comment: @mk8139 it's called foreach or enhanced for-loop and part of the language since Java 5.